# What version of LLVM and Clang is available in XCode 4.2?

Tags: xcode, macos, llvm, osx-lion, clang

What version of LLVM and Clang is available in XCode 4.2? I have searched a lot to try to find this information and the only thing i have seen is that it could be LLVM 3.0

Answer (score 2):

The version of llvm-gcc and clang in Xcode is not related to llvm.org releases.  They are branched from a random development version sometime in the lifetime of the development of that Xcode release.  If you're looking to know what features are available in Clang, please make use of the __has_feature capability:
http://clang.llvm.org/docs/LanguageExtensions.html#feature_check

Comment: Is it possible to get a build date.. Then i can look at the source tree for that date